# Linear regression error - line slope wrong

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, linear-regression, d

Consider this function:

```
double calculate_geoHeading(double [] x, double [] y) {

    /+ +++++++++
    ++ This function will return the heading of the best fit line
    ++
    +/

    double r;

    real xMean = mean(x);
    real yMean = mean(y);

    real denom = 0;
    real numer = 0;

    //double cookDistance NOIMPL

    for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        numer += (x[i] - xMean) * (y[i] - yMean);
        denom += (x[i] - xMean) * (x[i] - xMean);

    }

    real b1 = numer / denom ;
    real b0 = yMean - (b1 *xMean);  


    real y0 = b0 + b1 * x[0];
    real x0 = x[0];

    real yn = b0 + b1 * x[$-1];
    real xn = x[$-1];

    r = atan2((yn-y0), (xn-x0));                        

    foreach(XX; x) {

        auto YY =  b0 + b1 * XX;
        print_highPrecision_geoArray([YY, XX]);
    }

    return r;

}
```

It is written in D. Th array `x` is a double array of Longitudes, and `y` is for Latitude. I compute the linear regression through these points, and then compute the slope of this line. This slope is the heading of the path described by these points.

This normally Works,

For this input :

```
x = [9.87837003485911,9.87836998511341,9.87836993536771,9.878369885622,9.87836966666667,9.87836975210867,9.87836983755067,9.87836992299267,9.87837000843468,9.87837009387668]
y = 
[49.0199479977727,49.0199513307348,49.0199546636969,49.0199579966591,49.0199726666667,49.0199759989048,49.0199793311429,49.019982663381,49.0199859956191,49.0199893278572]
```

I am having this output :

[image]

The Red markers show you the first half of the input array, and the second half of the input array is given by the pink ones.

Then, I also have the output of the interpolated `y` or Latitude values. These values are held in function by the variable `YY`. The corresponding `x` or Longitude values are also present.

These interpolated points are also plotted . Half of them are in green - which has the same `x` values red part of the input. The rest are cyan, which corresponds to the pink part.

The input is a monotonically **increasing** function, whereas the interpolated output is monotonically decreasing.

**Question :** What is my error?

**My attempt at solution :** I have tried with 80 000 other randomly generated Lat / Lon pairs : it works everywhere in those pairs.

So, I am stuck.

The `print_highPrecision_geoArray` is properly defined, so is the `mean` function.

I do not want to blame this on a floating point error.
I need an algorithm, that applies the linear regression properly.

Please help.

Comment: You appear to have an almost vertical line. Maybe you need to transpose your coordinates when your slope is too large.

Comment: @stark why would it affect the regression ?

Comment: Because the slope of a vertical line is infinite.

Comment: @stark ok thank you.
it is 88 degrees tho. and in the generated random samples, it is catching all other lines within 85 to 95 degrees, including 90.03 degrees. could you please point me to some study material, so that i can fully understand which term of the formulae is causing the problem ? Thank you